# How to login a user from the Windows API (in Java)?

Tags: java, winapi, authentication

I don't want to go on to much and I don't have much time so I'm going to get straight to the point. How could I use the Windows API to log a user in or type in there password for them at the login screen in Windows?

My PC came with some facial recognition software that logs you in from the Windows login screen. If I lock my computer and the software is enabled, there's an "Other Credentials" button where "Switch User" usually is and by clicking it, it lets me choose to use the facial recognition instead of typing. The only reason I bring this up is that it's basically what I want to do: allow the user to log in using other methods rather than typing there password. I also noticed that I have to give the FR software my Windows password when I set it up so that interested me. I don't know... just a trail of thought.

The second part of my longer-than-expected question is how would I do this in Java?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to write a Windows GINA that would launch a JVM. It would have to provide JNI integration points with all of the GINA callbacks/passthru function that you cared about.

Writing a GINA is a difficult task (a co-worker of mine did one), and launching/integrating the JVM at this level is also a difficult task (I've done that). This was not a combined effort mind you, so doing the two of them together would be quite hard. It is do-able, I think, but I think you'd really have to ask yourself if its worth the effort.

If you do decide to do this, make sure you test your GINA in a virtual machine (you can use VirtualBox if you don't want to spend $$ on VMWare), and take snapshots of it before installing the GINA. If you screw up the GINA, its really easy to trash the Windows install.

Comment: Thanks, Bill but I just ran accross this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx and what I understand from it is that the GINA approach isn't used anymore since Vista. Your thoughts?

Comment: Same approach, but with the Credential Provider API rather than the GINA API I suppose. The GINA that my co-worker wrote was for XP. I didn't envy that him for getting that task. :-)

Comment: Cool. I'll look into it and post back later on. Thanks!